# Query for records that were active during a specified date range

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that records any time a certain field changes for an item, along with the date of the change. I need to query the data to find all items where that field had a specific value at any time during a requested date range.

In other words, if the item had that value at the start, end, or anytime during the data range, it should be included.

Example data:

```
Item  Valid  Date Changed
----  -----  ------------
A     Yes    2015-01-01

B     No     2015-01-01
B     Yes    2017-03-01

C     Yes    2015-01-01
C     No     2017-04-01

D     No     2015-01-01
D     Yes    2017-05-01
D     No     2017-06-01

E     Yes    2015-01-01
E     No     2017-05-01
E     Yes    2017-06-01

F     Yes    2015-01-01
F     No     2018-02-01

G     Yes    2017-12-31

V     No     2015-01-01
V     Yes    2018-02-01

W     Yes    2015-01-01
W     No     2016-01-01

X     No     2015-01-01

Y     Yes    2018-01-01

Z     Yes    2015-01-01
Z     No     2017-01-01
```

So if I need all Items that were valid during 2017, the query would include:

- A (Valid since 2015)
- B (Became valid during 2017)
- C (Was valid until mid-2017)
- D (Was valid for a month during 2017)
- E (Was valid at start and end of 2017)
- F (Was valid throughout 2017)
- G (Became valid during 2017)

The query would not include V, W, X, Y, or Z -- none of which were valid during 2017. (Pay special attention to G & Z, which are tricky edge cases!)

```
-- Sample data
create table #Temp (
    ItemID    char,
    Valid     bit,
    StartDate date
);

insert into #Temp (ItemID, Valid, StartDate)
values ('A', 1, '2015-01-01'),
       ('B', 0, '2015-01-01'),
       ('B', 1, '2017-03-01'),
       ('C', 1, '2015-01-01'),
       ('C', 0, '2017-04-01'),
       ('D', 0, '2015-01-01'),
       ('D', 1, '2017-05-01'),
       ('D', 0, '2017-06-01'),
       ('E', 1, '2015-01-01'),
       ('E', 0, '2017-05-01'),
       ('E', 1, '2017-06-01'),
       ('F', 1, '2015-01-01'),
       ('F', 0, '2018-02-01'),
       ('G', 1, '2017-12-31'),
       ('V', 0, '2015-01-01'),
       ('V', 1, '2018-02-01'),
       ('W', 1, '2015-01-01'),
       ('W', 0, '2016-01-01'),
       ('X', 0, '2015-01-01'),
       ('Y', 1, '2018-01-01'),
       ('Z', 1, '2015-01-01'),
       ('Z', 0, '2017-01-01');
```

FYI, here are some other SO questions I found that ask similar questions, but not exactly the same:

- [SQL query: list of all IDs that were active during a given time interval, sorted by their start-time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10851466/212978)
- [Extract signal state during specified time frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9108371/212978)
- [Query to find records that were active within a range of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787199/query-to-find-records-that-were-active-within-a-range-of-dates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can turn the original list of timestamps:

```
ItemID Valid StartDate
------ ----- ----------
A      1     2015-01-01
B      0     2015-01-01
B      1     2017-03-01
C      1     2015-01-01
C      0     2017-04-01
D      0     2015-01-01
D      1     2017-05-01
D      0     2017-06-01
E      1     2015-01-01
E      0     2017-05-01
E      1     2017-06-01
F      1     2015-01-01
F      0     2018-02-01
G      1     2017-12-31
V      0     2015-01-01
V      1     2018-02-01
W      1     2015-01-01
W      0     2016-01-01
X      0     2015-01-01
Y      1     2018-01-01
Z      1     2015-01-01
Z      0     2017-01-01
```

into a list of ranges, where the end date is either the item's next entry's `StartDate` or, if the current row is the last entry, today's date:

```
ItemID  Valid  StartDate   EndDate
------  -----  ----------  ----------
A       1      2015-01-01    (today)
B       0      2015-01-01  2017-03-01
B       1      2017-03-01    (today)
C       1      2015-01-01  2017-04-01
C       0      2017-04-01    (today)
D       0      2015-01-01  2017-05-01
D       1      2017-05-01  2017-06-01
D       0      2017-06-01    (today)
E       1      2015-01-01  2017-05-01
E       0      2017-05-01  2017-06-01
E       1      2017-06-01    (today)
F       1      2015-01-01  2018-02-01
F       0      2018-02-01    (today)
G       1      2017-12-31    (today)
V       0      2015-01-01  2018-02-01
V       1      2018-02-01    (today)
W       1      2015-01-01  2016-01-01
W       0      2016-01-01    (today)
X       0      2015-01-01    (today)
Y       1      2018-01-01    (today)
Z       1      2015-01-01  2017-01-01
Z       0      2017-01-01    (today)
```

You can use the [`LEAD` analytic function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) to achieve that:

```
EndDate = LEAD(StartDate, 1, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
          OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY StartDate ASC)
```

Once you have a list of ranges, it is easy to match the rows by using this established method of finding intersecting ranges (the ranges in the tables intersecting with the range specified in the query parameters):

```
StartDate < @EndDate AND EndDate > @StartDate
```

Here is the complete solution:

```
DECLARE
  @StartDate date = '2017-01-01',
  @EndDate   date = '2018-01-01',
  @ValidValue bit = 1
;

WITH
  ranges AS
  (
    SELECT
      ItemID,
      Valid,
      StartDate,
      EndDate = LEAD(StartDate, 1, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY StartDate ASC)
    FROM
      #Temp
  )
SELECT DISTINCT
  ItemID
FROM
  ranges
WHERE
  Valid = @ValidValue
  AND StartDate < @EndDate
  AND EndDate > @StartDate
;
```

You can play with this method in [this demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=555ad37c986d63d868780d5e362de5ed).

*Note: After completing my answer I realised that it ended up being very [similar to Sami's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54155896/297408). The difference is in handling the items' last entries.*

Comment: Using LEAD instead of LAG with today as the default date is a much cleaner way to get usable date ranges than the method I came up with. (I don't have much experience with these, but I had used LAG in another script recently, so grabbed it as a starting point.) Anyway, your version accomplishes in one step what I did in three. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
DECLARE @SD DATE = '2017-01-01',
        @ED DATE = '2017-12-31';

WITH BSD AS
(
SELECT *,
       LAST_VALUE(Valid) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY StartDate) LV,
       COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY StartDate DESC) CNT
FROM #Temp
WHERE StartDate <= @SD
)
SELECT ItemID
FROM BSD
WHERE LV = 1 AND CNT = 1
UNION 
SELECT ItemID
FROM #Temp
WHERE Valid = 1
      AND
      StartDate <= @ED
      AND
      StartDate >= @SD;
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=733d911d412b070b42582e631aa54dca)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
-- Date range includes all of 2017
declare
    @beginSearchDate date = '2017-01-01',
    @endSearchDate date = '2017-12-31';

with
    -- CTE: Existing data combined with current value as of today
    a as (
        select ItemID, Valid, StartDate
        from #Temp
        union
        select t1.ItemID, t1.Valid, convert(date, getdate())
        from (
                    select ItemID, max(StartDate) as LatestStartDate
                    from #Temp
                    group by ItemID
                ) as t2
                inner join #Temp as t1
                        on t1.ItemID = t2.ItemID
                            and t1.StartDate = t2.LatestStartDate
    ),
    -- CTE: Current and previous values included in each record
    b as (
        select a1.*,
                lag(a1.Valid) over ( partition by a1.ItemID order by a1.StartDate )
                    as PrevValid,
                lag(a1.StartDate) over ( partition by a1.ItemID order by a1.StartDate )
                    as PrevStartDate
        from a as a1
                inner join a as a2
                        on a1.ItemID = a2.ItemID
                            and a1.StartDate = a2.StartDate
    ),
    -- CTE: Values as a series of date ranges
    c as (
        select distinct ItemID,
                        StartDate     as UntilDate,
                        PrevValid     as Valid,
                        PrevStartDate as FromDate
        from b
        where PrevValid is not null
    )

-- Find all records where date range overlaps
select distinct ItemID
from c
where Valid = 1
    and FromDate <= @endSearchDate
    and UntilDate > @beginSearchDate
order by ItemID;
```

Result:

```
ItemID
------
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my swipe at it.  I build the first table with the items that had valid flag = 1 that fell anywhere below the end date.  This would account for Item A or any like it.

I then matched it up to the last invalid date for each item if it had one and then filtered it out by date.

```
declare
    @beginSearchDate date = '2017-01-01',
    @endSearchDate date = '2017-12-31';


;WITH CTE as (  
 select itemid, VALID, MAX(StartDate) stDate from #temp
       where valid <> 0 and StartDate <= @endSearchDate
           group by itemID, VALID

      )
    SELECT t1.ItemID, VALID , stDate 
        from CTE t1
        outer apply (
             SELECT ItemID, MAX(StartDate) inValDate from #Temp 
               where Valid = 0 
               and StartDate <= @endSearchDate 
               and ItemID = t1.ItemID GROUP BY ItemID) t2
    WHERE t2.inValDate IS NULL 
         or (t1.stDate > t2.inValDate OR t1.stDate > @beginSearchDate OR t2.inValDate > @beginSearchDate)
```